# How do I set the value for an array with specific number of division

Tags: php

How do I set the value for an array with division in specific number and the remaining of number will be loopback.

```
<?php
    $total = 125;
    $divide = 15;

    for($a=0; $a<=$divide; $a++)
    {
        $b[] = .....; //  $total/$divide
    }
print_r($b);
?>
```

The Ouput :

```
array([0]=>9[1]=>9[2]=>9[3]=>9[4]=>9[5]=>8[6]=>8[7]=>8..[14]=>8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
$total = 125;
$size = 15;

$chunk = floor($total / $size);
$mod = $total % $size;
if($mod)
    $result = array_fill(0, $mod, $chunk + 1) +
        array_fill($mod, $size - $mod, $chunk);
else
    $result = array_fill(0, $size, $chunk);
```

Comment: Will PHP recognise there are two lines following if with no braces?